# Missing `cfg80211` kernel module on KUbuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Intel WiFi card not working)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

Edit: Upon further investigation, it appears I am missing the `cfg80211` kernel module on which `iwlwifi` depends:

`modinfo cfg80211`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-104-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'cfg80211': No such file or directory
```

How can I rectify this?

Original question below:

I am installing a [`tp-link AC1200 Archer T5E`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084GT36WQ), the chipset is an intel `AC7265`.
I have tried downloading the appropriate firmware from [their website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html), copying it to `/lib/firmware/`, and rebooting without luck. According to the website, there is support for it built into the kernel I am using. Some command outputs:

`neofetch`

```
OS: KUbuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: MS-7C02 1.0 
Kernel: 5.4.0-104-generic
```

`lspci -nnk`

```
21:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
        DeviceName: Broadcom 5762
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`iwconfig` (I have a USB tether hooked up as a band-aid, `enp34s0` is ethernet)

```
usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp34s0   no wireless extensions.

br-4400933269a8  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list all` (I assume this is simply the dongle for my keyboard)

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:21:00.0
       version: 59
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7600000-f7601fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       logical name: enp34s0
       version: 15
       serial: 00:d8:61:e0:65:9b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:37 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 26:31:73:3a:64:4d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.117 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working for me:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Incremented the patch version, I am now on `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64` and everything works fine! `modinfo cfg80211` now shows info about the module as expected.